# IntentService working between Intents

Tags: android, android-activity, service, communication, intentservice

I don't know if this is possible, but I would like to do the next:

Imagine an app with 2 activities: MenuActivity and OtherPurposeActivity.

So, on the onCreate method of Menu I had run the Service. In the same Activity (Menu), I can easily "connect"(Edit: communicate) with this Service with no problems.

Then, I click the only button there is on MenuActivity, which starts OtherPurposeActivity. Here comes the question:

*How can I connect to the Service I had run on MenuActivity? Is it possible? (I hadn't called stopService).*

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    /* Execute service */
    Log.d("SERVICE", "Launching service");
    Intent msgIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, ServerProcessingService.class);
    msgIntent.setAction(ServerProcessingService.ACTION_STATUS);
    startService(msgIntent);


    /* Connection to the IntentService */
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(ServerProcessingService.ACTION_STATUS);
    //filter.addAction(ServerProcessingService.ACTION_CONTROL);
    rcv = new ProgressReceiver();
    registerReceiver(rcv, filter);

}
```

So I can handle the communication with the ProgressReceiver class. But, what if I open another activity, and this service still running? Can I access to it?

Comment: What does "connect" mean?  Code please.

Comment: No need to code. I can `startService(myService)` and communicate the service with a inner-class extending `BroadcastReceiver`. When I said "connect", I meant that: communicate.

Comment: Anyways I'll put the code.

Comment: Do you mean accessing the same instance of the service with some variables set by first Activity? Basically, there is always just one service running of the specific type.

Comment: you shouldn't use a BroadcasrReceiver here,  why don't you bind to your service?

Comment: @Loop Accessing the same instance of Service. In MenuActivity I access MyService. And in OtherActivity I access the Service opened in MenuActivity.

Comment: @pskink I'm trying to implement a Service which communicates via Internet with a Server. This service does 2 things: retrieve info and send info (obvious, or maybe not). I thought IntentService would be the best choice. It would be easier to start the activity in MenuActivity, and bind the other activity to the Service? How can I communicate? Similar way?

Comment: FYI: I'll be back in a few hours. Need a break :) Thx to all!

Comment: I still don't understand the question, really.  If you are asking whether the ServerProcessingService is a singleton, then the answer is yes.  To me, your code looks great, as it is: you send messages to the IntentService with an intent and you get responses with a broadcast.  The only think I'd change is that, to avoid a race, I'd register the receiver *before* I signaled the service....

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike i don't think BroadcastReceivers are the best means for Service - Activity communication, mainly because of efficiency and security

Comment: @pskink Yeah, could be.  Binding a service definitely has advantages (by my measurements, bound service calls are nearly two orders of magnitude faster).  It has disadvantages too, though (it is asynchronous).  If communication rates are slow (< ~10/sec) secured broadcasts seem like a reasonable option.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I connect to the Service I had run on MenuActivity?

Another activity that wants to communicate with the service can use exactly the same method as MenuActivity. `startService()` will only start the service if it is not already running, and then send the intent to `onStartCommand()` in all cases, so it is all right to call start service from multiple activities.

As a commenter pointed out, if your activity requires ongoing communication with a service, you should bind to it.

> Is it possible? (I hadn't called stopService).

An `IntentService` will stop itself if it has no work to do, so it doesn't matter that you did not stop it explicitly. If the service needs to continue running, don't use an intent service.

Answer (score 0):

To be on the same page I will describe briefly how I understood your dilemma.

You have an `IntentService` perfroming some operation which provides at the end some results. You are starting this process in one activity(asynchronously of course) and switch immediately to another one. Now, you are not sure whether service will finish the work before you switch to second `Activity` and result will be lost.

Basically, approach with `BroadcastReceiver` would be a good choice but if you won't register on time the data will be lost and service will end it's work. You could let the service to store the result before it ends, in DB, file or even in memory(depending on data type). When your second Activity start you can check if there is data waiting for you, if not you can wait for `BroadcastReceiver` to deliver it.

You could also use [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) library which is far more advanced solution than `BroadcastReceiver`. It allows to return to registered observer(`Activity`) the last result and what is more important it will allow your service to check if any observer received the message. If not you could only then store last result.